# Return first matching line

Tags: powershell

I have an XML command that returns a list of URLs, example

```
PS > $xml.rss.channel.item.link
http://example.com/20140704.exe
http://example.com/20140704.tar.xz
http://example.com/20140624.exe
http://example.com/20140624.tar.xz
http://example.com/20140507.tar.xz
```

From this list, I would like to return the first `.tar.xz` line. I have this
command

```sh
$xml.rss.channel.item.link | ? {$_ -match '.tar.xz'} | select -first 1
```

But I would prefer a command with only one pipe if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way using two pipes

```sh
$xml.rss.channel.item.link | Select-String .tar.xz | select -first 1
```

One pipe

```sh
($xml.rss.channel.item.link | Select-String .tar.xz)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a pipe at all:

```sh
(Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "(//link[contains(.,'.tar.xz')])[1]").Node.InnerText
```

Note: XPath is case-sensitive. If that is an issue, you can use a [trick with translate() function](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/01/pstip-using-xpath-in-powershell-part-5/) and force it to ignore the case.